# SQL Server Stored Procedure taking too long to retrive data from database

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that retrieves simple data from the table. For more than a year it was working just fine, but for couple of days it is taking more than 30 secs to select the data. Even sometimes it does not show anything on User Interface.

If I execute the same stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it takes 2-3 secs to execute. I tried to recompile table and procedure that is being used and also increased the Time out. But it didn't help and I need you suggestions.

Here below is my stored procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Monitoring_ver2]
    @AgentID int = NULL
 AS
 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 -- Insert statements for procedure here
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by AgentFullName ASC) as CodeID, res.*, DATEDIFF(mi, stsdate, getdate()) as MinFromLastSignal, DATEDIFF(MI, LastPaymentDateTime, getdate()) as MinFromLastPayment 
 from 
( 

     SELECT   s.AgentID, a.name+' '+a.surname as TerminalFullName, a.loginName, 
            s.KioskStatus, s.StsDate, s.TotalMoney, s.AmountMoney, s.MoneyInside, s.Version, s.PrinterErrorCode, s.ValidatorErrorCode,
            (select top(1) StatusDateTime from Payment where AgentID = s.AgentID order by PaymentID desc) as LastPaymentDateTime,
            prt.errtxt as PrinterErrorText, val.errtxt as ValidatorErrorText,
            s.IPAddress,
            b.AgentID as ParentID, b.[name]+' '+b.surname AS AgentFullName
            ,(SELECT TOP 1 i.RegDate FROM dbo.InkasaiyaOfTerm i WHERE i.AgentID=s.AgentID order by i.ID DESC) AS LastCollectionDate
            ,(SELECT TOP 1 i.Kol FROM dbo.InkasaiyaOfTerm i WHERE i.AgentID=s.AgentID order by i.ID DESC) AS LastCollectionQuantity
            ,(SELECT TOP 1 i.Summa FROM dbo.InkasaiyaOfTerm i WHERE i.AgentID=s.AgentID order by i.ID DESC) AS LastCollectionAmount
    FROM       StatusTerminal_ver2 s
                INNER JOIN ErrorCodeTerminal prt ON s.PrinterErrorCode = prt.ecode                
                INNER JOIN ErrorCodeTerminal val ON s.ValidatorErrorCode = val.ecode                
                INNER JOIN Agents a ON s.AgentID=a.AgentID
                INNER JOIN Agents b ON a.parentID=b.AgentID
    where s.AgentID IN (select AgentID FROM Agents WHERE hrccrt LIKE '%.'+CAST(@AgentID as varchar(10))+'.%' and agentType=2)
        and DATEDIFF(DAY, StsDate, GETDATE())<7
) as res
order by AgentFullName ASC
 END
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: You can add WITH NOLOCK after each table anem in FROM to improve performance.

Comment: Have you faced this kind of problem before?

Comment: Firstly, I guest your SELECT from many tables with the frequently change quite high, your table can under many transactions so the  tables are locked when selected can occurred. Other side I will suggest you look at the Query Analyzer to find out where the bottle neck to improve performance so far.

Comment: Throwing NO LOCK hints into a query may well improve performance but probably at the expense of correctness. You need to dig a bit deeper - has this suddenly started or has there actually been a slow deterioration that has only just been brought to your attention?

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan from ssms - on the top ribbon click include actual execution plan. This will tell you pretty much straight away where the bottleneck is

Comment: Was there ever maintanance on the database? Try a) to clear tempdb. b) rebuild indexes

Comment: @lordkain I tried both, but still it is taking too long to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure at the beginning set:

SET ARITHABORT ON

If it doesn't make any difference then cause my parameter sniffing. The sql server has complied the query on the basis of first parameter you have passed and generated the execution plan. This plan may be bad for other parameters. You can use optimize for clause.